# Forcing steps with django form wizard

Tags: python, django

How would I force steps for the [django form wizard](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)?

I have step 0 showing a Subscription page with different account types.

I wanted to have the ability to send someone a link such as ***/join/basic or /join/pro***

And have that link forward them to the correct step/form.

Ive found:

> [FormWizard.parse_params()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.FormWizard.parse_params)
>
> A hook for saving state from the request object
>   and args / kwargs that were captured
>   from the URL by your URLconf.
>
> By default, this does nothing.

Not sure how I could use this to change the form that is validated/rendered

Comment: may be a bug in django :( http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15075

Comment: http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/16119

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle the "switch form" behaviour here:

```
FormWizard.process_step()
```

There you the data from previous submitted (and valid) form and is supposed to be the place where you "change the internal state" of the wizard (eg. to change the form list)

Note that the method is called every time a step is processed.

Docs here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.FormWizard.process_step